# Xamarin cross-platform circular image

Tags: image, listview, xamarin.forms, imageview

How do you create circular clipping mask for images which works in Xamarin Cross-Platform, and how do you implement it within a ListView? I don't want to use plugins. I found some examples but they all target Android Apps only and most of them are written in Java, not C#.

Comment: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/ImageCirclePlugin - if you don't want to use the plugin, then review the source to see how they achieved the effect

Comment: @Jason yes, it did the trick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needs to Write [CustomRederers](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/entry/) for Image

**PCL:**

**ImageCircle.cs**

```
public class ImageCircle : Image
{

}
```

**Xamarin.Android:**

**ImageCircleRenderer.cs**

**Above NameSpace**
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ImageCircle), typeof(ImageCircleRenderer))]

```
 public class ImageCircleRenderer : ImageRenderer
  {

    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Image> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.OldElement == null)
        {

            if ((int)Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt < 18)
                SetLayerType(LayerType.Software, null);
        }
    }

    protected override bool DrawChild(Canvas canvas, global::Android.Views.View child, long drawingTime)
    {
        try
        {
            var radius = Math.Min(Width, Height) / 2;
            var strokeWidth = 10;
            radius -= strokeWidth / 2;


            Path path = new Path();
            path.AddCircle(Width / 2, Height / 2, radius, Path.Direction.Ccw);
            canvas.Save();
            canvas.ClipPath(path);

            var result = base.DrawChild(canvas, child, drawingTime);

            canvas.Restore();

            path = new Path();
            path.AddCircle(Width / 2, Height / 2, radius, Path.Direction.Ccw);

            var paint = new Paint();
            paint.AntiAlias = true;
            paint.StrokeWidth = 5;
            paint.SetStyle(Paint.Style.Stroke);
            paint.Color = global::Android.Graphics.Color.White;

            canvas.DrawPath(path, paint);

            paint.Dispose();
            path.Dispose();
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var msg = ex.Message;
        }

        return base.DrawChild(canvas, child, drawingTime);
    }

}
```

**Xamarin.iOS**

**Above NameSpace** 
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ImageCircle), typeof(ImageCircleRender))]

**ImageCircleRenderer.cs**

```
  public class ImageCircleRender : ImageRenderer
{
    protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Image> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (e.OldElement != null || Element == null)
            return;

        CreateCircle();
    }

    protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);

        if (e.PropertyName == VisualElement.HeightProperty.PropertyName ||
            e.PropertyName == VisualElement.WidthProperty.PropertyName)
        {
            CreateCircle();
        }
    }
    private void CreateCircle()
    {
        try
        {
            double min = Math.Min(Element.Width, Element.Height);
            Control.Layer.CornerRadius = (float)(min / 2.0);
            Control.Layer.MasksToBounds = false;
            Control.Layer.BorderColor = Color.White.ToCGColor();
            Control.Layer.BorderWidth = 1;
            Control.ClipsToBounds = true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Unable to create circle image: " + ex);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Use  https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugins.Forms.ImageCircle

In your iOS, Android, and Windows projects call:
Xamarin.Forms.Init();//platform specific init
ImageCircleRenderer.Init();